# Xcode 15 - Preview macro error with UIKit UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xcode15, xcode-previews

In my legacy code base with public Xcode 15.0, I can't preview any UIKit views with the new **#Preview** macro

```swift
import SwiftUI

#Preview {
    let uiView = UIView()

    return uiView
}
```

The canvas fails to load preview with failure diagnostic
`Compiling failed: return expression of type 'UIView' does not conform to 'View'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I find that restricting this one-statement preview to iOS 17 works:

```
@available(iOS 17, *)
#Preview {
    return UIView()
}
```

However, this two-statement preview still does not work:

```
@available(iOS 17, *)
#Preview {
    let uiView = UIView()
    return uiView //  Value of optional type 'UIView?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIView'
}
```

To get the two-statement preview to work, I have to make the variable type explicit:

```
@available(iOS 17, *)
#Preview {
    let uiView: UIView = UIView()
    return uiView
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The #Preview macro started working after I marked it @available(iOS 17, *)